# Html5-QRCode trouble detecting barcode because of photo quality

Tags: javascript, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to detect barcodes, EAN 13. More precisely the ISBN of several books, the ISBN is unique number to identify a book.)
I am using Html5-QRCode (Easy Mode). It works well, but it struggles to detect it, takes some time. If I upload a picture, instead of 'live' scanning it, i can see the picture looses significant quality. So I guess that is the problem. Here is an example of what can actually gets uploaded:

[image: what actually gets uploaded].

here is part of the JS code:

```
let html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
      "reader",
      { fps: 5, qrbox: {width: 300, height: 150} },
      /* verbose= */ false);
      html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanFailure);
```

is their an argument to change the image quality (or any other suggestions)? sorry if i haven't read the doc properly but I couldn't seem to find it.
Even if it is not at all critical any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since [easy mode](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/blob/master/README.md#easy-mode---with-end-to-end-scanner-user-interface) is the problem, why not change to [pro mode](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/blob/master/README.md#pro-mode---if-you-want-to-implement-your-own-user-interface)?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks! i thought it was already possible to change image properties (on 'L3'). I thought 'pro mode' was only for the UI.

Comment: In the end, I couldn't have it work properly with pro mode either.

Comment: It looks like the library scans the frontend div for a code. After some testing I was able to scan QR codes using a large desktop window and not being able to scan the same code using my iPhone. I found this Github issue to support this theory: https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/issues/410#issuecomment-1032423775.